# Is there a safe and efficient way to fill NaNs in pandas only in a specific time range of the day?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, fillna, chained-assignment

I know that chained-assignment in pandas is definitely a hot topic and there are a huge amount of questions on it but I am still unable to find a solution that works in my case.

I am working with irradiance and pv time series data (pandas dataframe with DateTimeIndex). There are holes in my series, some during night-time others during day-time. I would like to replace all the NaNs during the night-time with zeros because it would make sense (irradiance and pv production during night are null).

What I came up with so far is something like:

```
hour_range = [*range(17, 24)] + [*range(0, 9)]
mask = df['irradiance'].isna() & df['irradiance'].index.hour.isin(hour_range)
df.loc[mask, 'irradiance'] = 0
```

I tried also other solutions, like combining `between_time` with `fill_na` or using directly `df.mask` with the `in_place` option but I keep getting the dreaded `SettingWithCopyWarning`. I decided not to use `between_time` because it does not return a boolean series and does not allow combinining easily multiple conditions. Maybe I am wrong on this.
I would like to modify the df in_place for memory efficiency.
Is there a cleaner and safer solution to my problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to create a time range (if needed), how to create an array of time you wish to manipulate, and how to alter the 'Data' column based on the "time to manipulate" array

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

#Making example data
start_date = datetime.datetime.now()
period_end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
dates = np.arange(np.datetime64(start_date), np.datetime64(period_end_date), np.timedelta64(1, 'h'), dtype='datetime64[h]')
data = np.random.randint(1, 100, 24)
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns = ['Dates'])
df['Data'] = data
df['Data'] = np.where(df['Data']%2 == 0, np.nan, df['Data'])

#Creating a dynamic time range and replaceing nan with "Something Else"
start_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours = 5)
end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(hours = 5)
#Creates a time range you which to manipulate
time_range = np.arange(np.datetime64(start_time), np.datetime64(end_time), np.timedelta64(1, 'h'), dtype='datetime64[h]')
#Replaces all the np.nan within the "time_range" variable with "Something Else" otherwise leave it as it is
df['Data'] = np.where((df['Dates'].isin(time_range)), df['Data'].fillna('Something Else'), df['Data'])
```